# A question on relations

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations

> **Problem Statement:**
>
> Let $A$ and $B$ be sets. Many books define a relation $\mathcal R$ from $A$ to $B$ to be a
>   subset $
> \mathcal R \subseteq A \times B $.
>
> Show that such an R is a relation on A∪B according
>   to the following definition :
>
> **Definition:**
>
> A relation $\mathcal R $ on a set $S$ is a collection of ordered pairs
>   of elements of $S$; that is, a subset $ \mathcal R \subseteq S \times S$.
>
> The assertion $(x, y) \in \mathcal R$ is
>   usually abbreviated $x \mathcal Ry$, and we say $x$ is related to $y$ by $ \mathcal R.$ If $(x, y)  \notin \mathcal R$
>
> we write $ x \not \mathcal R y$.

How would approach  this problem? I don't quite understand how to. It seems rather ambiguous and obvious

Comment: Why would you be required to prove that?  Also, this is trivial to prove.

Comment: @EricTowers Yes it would be. I don't understand how I would prove that $\mathcal R$ is relation in turn of $A \cup B$

Comment: What is the actual problem/question that you are trying to answer?  There is no problem statement nor theorem statement in the quoted material.

Comment: If $R\subseteq A\times B$ then also $R\subseteq S\times S$ where $S=A\cup B$. Along this a relation $R$ from $A$ to $B$ can be interpreted as a relation on $S=A\cup B$.

Comment: @drhab The question seems a bit pointless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $S = A \cup B$, let $\mathcal{R} \subseteq A \times B$, and let $(x,y) \in \mathcal{R}$.  Then $x \in A \subseteq S$ and $y \in B \subseteq S$, so $(x,y) \in S \times S$.  Therefore $\mathcal{R} \subseteq S \times S$.

(At least, I think that's what's being asked...)